# How to store an array of pixels into a 2D array?

Tags: java, image, opencv

I am trying to load a given images pixel RGB values into a 2d array so that I can later edit them.
for example, if I have a pixel at 500,350 it's pixel value will look something like R 250 G 245 B 210

I am trying to have it get into a 2d array where it looks like this

```
A 2-dimensional array of pixels:
[
  [(255,45,19), (44,44,92), (80,1,9), ...],
  [(51,2,231), (61,149,14), (234,235,211), ...],
  [(51,2,231), (61,149,14), (199,102,202)...],
  [(51,2,231), (61,149,14), (1,5,42)...],
  ...
]
```

This is using the OpenCV library for java **I have tried** to do something like,

```java
int[][] pixelArray = int[image.rows()][image.cols()];

for (int i = 0;i<image.rows();i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<image.cols();j++){
        double[] pixelValues = image.get(i,j);
        pixelArray[i][j] = pixelValues; 
   }
}
```

My thinking here was to add an array as an element of the 2d array but I think my logic is flawed since this does not pan out so well

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Instantiating ImageCodecs Class
    Imgcodecs imageCodecs = new Imgcodecs();

    //Loads Image
    Mat image = imageCodecs.imread(imageInput);
    System.out.println("Image Loaded");
    System.out.println("Image size: " + image.rows() + " Pixel rows " + image.cols() + " Pixel columns "  );

    //Gets pixel RGB values
    double[] rgb = image.get(0,0);
    System.out.println("red: " + rgb[0] + " Green: " + rgb[1] + " Blue: " + rgb[2]);

    // Attempt to get all pixels in 2D array
    int[][] pixelArray = int[image.rows()][image.cols()];

    for (int i = 0;i<image.rows();i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<image.cols();j++){
            double[] pixelValues = image.get(i,j);
            pixelArray[i][j] = pixelValues; //TRYING TO FILL 2D ARRAY WITH REGULAR ARRAY
        }
    }
    ...
```

I should be able to print the RGB values of the entire 2d array

Answer (score 0):

I would create a `Pixel` class, and then have a 2-d array of `Pixel` objects. If you override the `toString` method you can control how the class will appear when you print it out.

```
public class Pixel {
  private int red;
  private int green;
  private int blue;

  public Pixel(int red, int green, int blue) {
      this.red = red;
      this.green = green;
      this.blue = blue;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
      return "R: " + red +
              "G: " + green +
              "B: " + blue;
  }
}
```

To print out the array, you can then just do:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Color class and use an array of Color[] colors? It has methods to get the RGB components and to convert from int to Color and back again?

```java
      List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<>();
      color.add(new Color(255,45,19));
      color.add(new Color(44,44,92));
```

or

```java
      Color[] colors = new Color[10];
      colors[0] = new Color(255,45,19);
      colors[1] = new Color(44,44,92);
```

To store in a 2D array its best to do it like this.

```java
int NROWS = 200;
int NCOLS = 200;
Color[][]  colors = new Color[NROWS][];
for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
     Color[] row = new Color[NCOLS];
     for (int c = 0; c < NCOLS; c++) {
          //each element in a row is part of a column
          row[c] = new Color(......);
     }
      colors[r] = row;
}
```

Whether you store as colors some other data structure, the same idea applies.  You may also want to investigate using a `raster` to store the pixels.

Comment: this is gonna blow out your memory - but it's ok as a concept - I'm not sure if the user wants it - I'm not sure the user is sure what he wants

Comment: @gpasch You may be correct.  Perhaps the OP should consider using a raster.  But it could still be a memory hog.